# Determine if all lines were faulty or some were correct--error handling in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a structure like as below, for error handling.

```
    On error resume next
    Statement1
    Statement2
    Statement3
    On error goto 0
```

I need to determine if all of the 3 statements were faulty or at least one of them was correct.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you defining *faulty*? The code throws an error or, for example, a statement returns 'false' (e.g. you say that at least one statement must be correct)?

Comment: If the code throws an error for a statement, that statement is "faulty". Simply put, did all the statements give error or at least one statement was ok?

Comment: That's an indication that you need to break it down to 3 individual functions, each one reporting its result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a bypass section (Error Handling) so that when it errors, it'll action that specific chunk of code and then continue where you were.

```
Sub Test
dim E1 as boolean
dim E2 as boolean
dim E3 as boolean

[any other code here]

On Error goto Err1Fail
Statement1
ResumeErr1Fail:
On Error Goto Err2Fail
Statement2
ResumeErr2Fail:
On Error Goto Err3Fail
Statement3
ResumeErr3Fail:
On Error Goto 0

[rest of code]

Exit Sub

'Error Handling Section
Err1Fail:
E1 = TRUE
resume ResumeErr1Fail
exit sub

Err2Fail:
E2 = TRUE
resume ResumeErr2Fail
exit sub

Err3Fail:
E3 = TRUE
resume ResumeErr3Fail
exit sub

End Sub
```

In the [rest of the code] section, you can then evaluate E1, E2 and E3 to do whatever you need to with them.

Answer (score 2):

As with any problem, there are many ways it can be solved.  Sticking with the error handling idea, you could structure the code like this:

```
Private Sub Test()
   On Error Resume Next
   
   Dim atLeastOne As Integer
   
   Err.Clear
   Debug.Print 1 / 0
   If Err.Number = 0 Then atLeastOne = atLeastOne + 1

   Err.Clear
   Debug.Print 1 / 1
   If Err.Number = 0 Then atLeastOne = atLeastOne + 1

   Err.Clear
   Debug.Print 1 / 0
   If Err.Number = 0 Then atLeastOne = atLeastOne + 1
   
   MsgBox atLeastOne
End Sub
```